# Extracting data from hyperlink cell in CSV

Tags: python, csv

When I am reading a cell with hyperlink from CSV file I am getting the following:

`=HYPERLINK("http://google.com","google") #for example`

Is there a way to extract only the `"google"` without the `=hyperlink` and the link?

Comment: Can you be sure the name will be given inside quotation marks? If so, you can use `split` method for strings

Comment: Which `"google"` do you want to extract (there are two)? The Excel **HYPERLINK** function accepts one or two arguments. The first is called `link_location` and can be a quoted string or a reference to specific cell in the document. The optional second argument is called `friendly_name` and likewise be a string literal or cell reference. To properly process  cells containing hyperlinks will require extracting each argument and handling both possibilities. How that is does will depend on exactly what module you're using to read the CSV file.

Comment: Hmm so i m using the csv class for pythin a d just extracting the value of the cell, the value that i get is the one in the question. I do want to get only the friendky name, is there a method to do that, or is the ony way is to use the "split"?

Comment: There's no built-in function to do it, so you will need to parse the contents of the cell. Splitting on a comma alone doesn't seem like it would be enough. I think you will need to use a regular expression via the `re` module to recognize **HYPERLINK** calls and extract the one or two possible arguments that they can be passed. You also need to decide what to do when there's no `friendly_name` argument, which is a possibility.

Answer (score 1):

As per @martineau's comment, you have two versions of `HYPERLINK`.

```
>>> s1 = '=HYPERLINK("http://google.com","google")'
```

Or

```
>>> s2 = '=HYPERLINK("http://google.com")'
```

You can `split`, use a regex, but these methods are tricky (what if you have a comma in the url? an escaped quote in the name?).

There is a module called [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) that parses Python expressions. We can use it, because Excel function call syntax is close to Python's one. Here's a version that returns the friendly name if there is one, and the url else:

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.parse(s1[1:]).body[0].value.args[-1].s
'google'
```

And:

```
>>> ast.parse(s2[1:]).body[0].value.args[-1].s
'http://google.com'
```

This is how it works: `s1[1:]` removes the `=` sign. Then we take the value of the expression:

```
>>> v = ast.parse(s1[1:]).body[0].value
>>> v
<_ast.Call object at ...>
```

It is easy to extract the function name:

```
>>> v.func.id
'HYPERLINK'
```

And the args:

```
>>> [arg.s for arg in v.args]
['http://google.com', 'google']
```

Just take the last arg ( `....args[-1].s) to get the friendly name if it exists, and the url else. You can also check`len(args)` to do something if there is one arg, and something else if there are two args.